# Changing attribute of a DOM element using D3 data that is bound to it

Tags: jquery, dom, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

I have a D3.js visualization of a DAG, using the force-directed layout.  Sometimes I want to change the colours of certain nodes.  So far, I have done this in click listeners by using `this`:

```
function clickNode(node) {
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", nodeHighlightColour);
}
```

However, now I want to change node colour in a function that is *called* by a listener, instead of the listener itself.  The reason it has to be a separate function is that I want to "highlight" a series of nodes, tracing back from the node that's clicked, so I need to call the function (`tracePath`) recursively.

If I call `tracePath` from the listener, I get an "undefined function" runtime error when I try `d3.select(this).attr("fill")`.  I'm guessing this is because `this` is no longer in the scope.  I can pass the `node` object to `tracePath`, but this is the node data rather than the DOM element.  How do I get the DOM element using just the data object that is bound to it?

**EDIT:**
As I wrote in my comment to Felix Kling, I can't simply pass `this` to `tracePath`.  This will work for the first node, but I still have to call the function recursively.  Here is my `tracePath` function so far:

```
// Trace the back from a node - node_el is "this", node is the node data
function tracePath(node_el, node) {
    var this_id = node.id;

    if (node.logic == null) {
            console.log("Highlighting!");
            // Using "this" to change colour
            d3.select(node_el).attr("fill", nodeHighlightColour);
    }
    // Look for edges that point to this node
    for (var i=0; i<edges.length; i++) {
            var e = edges[i];
            if (e.target == this_id) {
                    var next_node = None;

                    // Get the node at the source of the edge
                    for (var j = 0; j<nodes.length; j++) {
                        if (nodes[j].id == e.source) {
                            next_node = nodes[j];
                        }
                    }
                    // Recursively trace back from that node
                    if (next_id != None) {
                            // How do I get the DOM element to pass to tracepath?
                            tracePath(???, next_node);
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` *is* the DOM element, so just pass `this` to `tracePath`?

Comment: @FelixKling Oh haha thanks... should have thought of that.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually that doesn't quite do it... because I need to call `tracePath` recursively on a different node.  I can get the node data by getting its `id` from the relevant edges, but I still need access to its DOM element.  I'll edit my question, sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: If you set up your code so that you give the SVG elements that represent the nodes an ID (equivalent to the `id` value of your node data), then you can use `document.getElementById(next_id)` to get a reference to the next node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Felix Kling for the answer to this!  As he suggested, I added an `id` to each SVG circle element that was the same as the node data id, like this:

```
 circle = d3.select('#graphics').append("g").selectAll("circle")
         .data(force.nodes())
         .enter().append("svg:circle")
         .attr("id", function(d) {
              return d.id;
         })
         .on("click", clickNode)
```

Then, I could access the DOM element using the node id.  Here is my finished `tracePath` function:

```
// Trace the path back from a node
function tracePath(node_el, node) {
    var this_id = node.id;
    console.log("in tracepath");
    if (node.logic == null) {
            console.log("Highlighting!");
            d3.select(node_el).attr("fill", nodeHighlightColour);
    }
    console.log("this_id:", this_id);
    // Look for edges that point to this node
    for (var i=0; i<edges.length; i++) {
            var e = edges[i];
            if (e.target.id == this_id) {
                    console.log("edge from ", e.source.name);

                    // Recursively trace back from that node
                    var next_el = document.getElementById(e.source.id);
                    tracePath(next_el, e.source);
            }
    }
}
```

I also noticed that `e.target` (where `e` is an edge) gives me the target node itself, not just the id, so I didn't need to search through the nodes.